# Can 2 WPF datagrids be synced up based on a column?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I was wondering how to sync up 2 grids based on a value in a column. For example I have 2 grids with log information ordered by date from 2 different sources. They do not have the same # of records in them. If I move the top one, I would need the bottom grid to reposition based on the date column in the first one. This way info from the 2 logs can be presented together without the user having to do the searching.. Can this be done? Each log contains different types of errors/trace info and displaying the 2 in sync based on a date presents more info quicker to the user for debugging research.

Thanks
Harold

Comment: Does 'grid' mean 'datagrid'?  Suggesting an edit to clarify this

Comment: yes a datagrid, specifically the xceed community controls datagrid

Comment: You could trigger the scroll of the 2nd grid from activity on the first grid, but I would implement it with a button called "Synchronize" and make it user initiated.  That way your feature can be precisely tested